# Selecting default action on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, android-activity

I am trying to build an application that would replace a default action on Android. The problem is that when action should be performed i get "Select Action" dialog with no checkbox to select it as default. I think i should be getting "Complete Action Using" dialog (which in turn has the checkbox). I do not understand how I can make Android to offer me the "Complete ..." dialog. My manifest file is as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="si.cetrtapot.mobiris"
          android:versionName="1.0"
          android:versionCode="1" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" 
                  android:required="true" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:debuggable="true" >

        <activity android:name=".ReadTagActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                       android:resource="@xml/nfc" />
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The way intent-filters work is that the PackageManager has all these applications registered with it via the Manifest that is found per application. Specifically when an application falls un a certain Intent-Filter, it will then be added to the list of applications that have those kinds of Intent-Filters declared in their Manifest.

For instance say my application, handles the: [Intent.ACTION_SEND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) this means that my application will show up in the list of application that hand particular action. Which would include, the default MMS/SMS application and any other applications the user has that has this, including **MY** application if the user has it installed.

You should begin by understanding what "default action" even means. Understanding this will help you how to solve your problem.

For your reference:

[Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

[Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_DEFAULT)

Comment: I am not sure if you understand my question. My application IS in the list of default actions. The problem is in the select dialog that I get when the action should be performed. Usually you would get: "Complete Action Using" dialog. But I get "Select Action" dialog. the difference is that the later does not have a checkbox to select default application. My question is why do I get the "Select..." dialog and not the "Complete..." dialog.

Comment: post the code that is starting this dialog then maybe we'll have our answer.

Comment: This dialog is started by Android OS when android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED action happens. see: http://shrani.si/f/2U/5D/1IMhNENB/device-2012-02-01-094703.png

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that anything is wrong. I don't believe NFC intents were meant to have a default app unless you have very specific intent filtering for Ndef formatted cards. I did this for my job because we wanted just our app to pop up with our tag. Otherwise it would just be in a list all the time (which is annoying).